# Surprising expansion of variadic GNU C preprocessor macros in the presence of the ## operator

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

If we define a macro

```
#define M(x, ...) { x, __VA_ARGS__ }
```

and then use it passing itself as an argument

```
M(M(1, 2), M(3, 4), M(5, 6))
```

then it expands to the expected form:

```
{ { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } }
```

However, when we use the `##` operator (to prevent dangling comma from appearing in the output in the case of the single argument invocations, as documented [in the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)), i.e.

```
#define M0(x, ...) { x, ## __VA_ARGS__ }
```

then the expansion of arguments in

```
M0(M0(1,2), M0(3,4), M0(5,6))
```

seems to stop after the first argument, i.e. we get:

```
{ { 1,2 }, M0(3,4), M0(5,6) }
```

Is this behavior a bug, or does it stem from some principle?

(I have also checked it with clang, and it behaves in the same way as GCC)

Comment: @EugeneSh. it concerns the same question; in the comment jdolan claims that "The GCC manual says that "pasted tokens" (anything after ##) are not expanded", but he failed to give a pointer to the manual.

Comment: When I use two macros with different names, e.g. `M0(x, ...)` and `N0(x, ...)` with the same expansion it works for me if I use e.g. `N0(M0(1,2), M0(3,4), M0(5,6))` or `N0(M0(1), M0(3), M0(5))`. (I don't know if this is guaranteed behavior.)

Comment: And for me also this version works `#define M1(...) { __VA_ARGS__ }` when used as `M1(M1(1, 2), M1(3, 4), M1(5, 6))` or `M1(M1(1), M1(3), M1(5))`.

Comment: @bodo yes, I eventually went with `...` and `__VA_ARGS__` without `##`, but I have wasted considerable amount of time to deal with the weird behavior that I still don't understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Way down at the end of this answer there is a possible solution.

> Is this behavior a bug, or does it stem from some principle?

It stems from two principles whose interaction is pretty subtle. So I agree that it is surprising, but it's not a bug.

The two principles are the following:

1. Inside the replacement of macro invocation, that macro is not expanded. (See the [GCC Manual Section 3.10.5, Self-Referential Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html#Self-Referential-Macros) or the C Standard, §6.10.3.4 paragraph 2.) This  precludes recursive macro expansion, which in most cases would produce infinite recursion if allowed. Although it is likely that no-one anticipated such uses, it turns out that there would be ways of using recursive macro expansion which would not result in infinite recursion (see the [Boost Preprocessor Library documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) for a [thorough discussion of this issue](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/topics/reentrancy.html)), but the standard isn't going to get changed now.
2. If `##` is applied to a macro argument, it suppresses macro expansion of that argument. (See the [GCC Manual section 3.5, Concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) or the C Standard, §6.10.3.3 paragraph 2.) The suppression of expansion is part of the C Standard, but GCC/Clang's extension to allow use of `##` to conditionally suppress the comma preceding `__VA_ARGS__` is non-standard. (See the [GCC Manual Section 3.6, Variadic Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).) Apparently, the extension still respects the standard's rule about not expanding concatenated macro arguments.

Now, the curious thing about the second point, with respect to optional comma suppression, is that you hardly ever notice it in practice. You can use `##` to conditionally suppress commas and arguments will still get expanded as normal:

```
#define SHOW_ARGS(arg1, ...) Arguments are (arg1, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#define DOUBLE(a) (2 * a)
SHOW_ARGS(DOUBLE(2))
SHOW_ARGS(DOUBLE(2), DOUBLE(3))
```

This expands to:

```
Arguments are ((2 * 2))
Arguments are ((2 * 2), (2 * 3))
```

Both `DOUBLE(2)` and `DOUBLE(3)` are expanded normally, despite the fact that one of them is an argument to the concatenation operator.

But there's a subtlety to macro expansion. Expansion happens twice:

1. First, macro arguments are expanded. (This expansion is in the context of the text which invokes the macro.) These expanded arguments are substituted for the parameters in the macro replacement body (but only where the parameter is not an argument to `#` or `##`).
2. Then the `#` and `##` operators are applied to the replacement token list.
3. Finally, the resulting replacement tokens are inserted into the input stream, so that they are expanded again. This time, the expansion is in the context of the macro so recursive invocation is suppressed.

With that in mind, we see that in `SHOW_ARGS(DOUBLE(2), DOUBLE(3))`, `DOUBLE(2)` is expanded in step 1, before being inserted into the replacement token list, and `DOUBLE(3)` is expanded in step 3, as part of the replacement token list.

This doesn't make a difference with `DOUBLE` inside `SHOW_ARGS`, since they're different macros. But the difference would become apparent if they were the same macro.

To see the difference, consider the following macro:

```
#define INVOKE(A, ...) A(__VA_ARGS__)
```

That macro creates a macro invocation (or a function invocation, but here we're only interested in the case where it's a macro). That is, in turns `INVOKE(X, Y)` into `X(Y)`. (That's a simplification of a useful feature, where the named macro is actually invoked several times, possibly with slightly different arguments.)

That works fine with `SHOW_ARGS`:

```
INVOKE(SHOW_ARGS, one arg)

⇒ Arguments are (one arg)
```

But if we try to `INVOKE` the macro `INVOKE` itself, we find that the ban on recursive invocation takes effect:

```
INVOKE(INVOKE, SHOW_ARGS, one arg)

⇒ INVOKE(SHOW_ARGS, one arg)
```

"Of course", we could expand `INVOKE` as an argument to `INVOKE`:

```
INVOKE(SHOW_ARGS, INVOKE(SHOW_ARGS, one arg))

⇒ Arguments are (Arguments are (one arg))
```

That works fine because there is no `##` inside `INVOKE`, so expansion of the argument is not suppressed. But if the expansion of the argument had been suppressed, then the argument would be inserted into the macro body unexpanded, and then it would become a recursive expansion.

So that's what is going on in your example:

```
#define M0(x, ...) { x, ## __VA_ARGS__ }
M0(M0(1,2), M0(3,4), M0(5,6))

⇒ { { 1,2 }, M0(3,4), M0(5,6) }
```

Here, the first argument to the outer `M0`, `M0(1,2)`, is not used with `##`, so it is expanded as part of the invocation. The other two arguments are part of `__VA_ARGS__`, which is used with `##`. Consequently, they are not expanded prior to being substituted into the macro's replacement list. But as part of the macro's replacement list, their expansion is suppressed by the no-recursive-macros rule.

You can easily work around that by defining two versions of the `M0` macro, with the same contents but different names (as suggested in a comment to the OP):

```
#define M0(x, ...) { x, ## __VA_ARGS__ }
M0(M1(1,2), M1(3,4), M1(5,6))

⇒ { { 1,2 }, { 3,4 }, { 5,6 } }
```

But that's not very pleasant.

#### Solution: Use `__VA_OPT__`

C++2a will include a new feature designed specifically to assist with suppressing commas in variadic invocations: the `__VA_OPT__` function-like macro. Inside a variadic macro expansion, `__VA_OPT__(x)` expands to its argument provided that there is at least one token in the variadic arguments. But if `__VA_ARGS__` expands to an empty token list, so does `__VA_OPT__(x)`. Thus, `__VA_OPT__(,)` can be used for conditional suppression of a comma just like the GCC `##` extension, but unlike `##`, it does not trigger suppression of macro expansion.

As an extension to the C standard, recent versions of GCC and Clang implement `__VA_OPT__` for C as well as C++. (See the [GCC Manual Section 3.6, Variadic Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).) So if you're willing to rely on relatively recent compiler versions, there is a very clean solution:

```
#define M0(x, ...) { x __VA_OPT__(,) __VA_ARGS__ }
M0(M0(1,2), M0(3,4), M0(5,6))

⇒ { { 1 , 2 } , { 3 , 4 }, { 5 , 6 } }
```

---

#### Notes:

1. You can see these examples on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/c3yWSo)
2. This question was originally closed as a duplicate of [Variadic macros: expansion of pasted tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27514116/variadic-macros-expansion-of-pasted-tokens) but I don't think that answer is really adequate to this particular situation.